# How can i assign a specific id to lookup during the quick action?

Tags: custom-button, quickaction

We have Object A, B.
A has quick action with lookup field to B. Is it possible to set quick action as hard coded id for the reference to B for specific record? When I try to add Id of B(lookup) the formula is giving error, is it possible or not?
[image]

Comment: I have never done or tried this, but only by looking at this it does not makes sense to hardcode an id as it would change with every org.

Comment: Yes it will change with diff org but we can change that in diff org with the actual record id that we created in new org.